# Inserting Foreign Key using MySQL Workbench code throwing Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have created several tables with MySQL Workbench and I'm having a problem with Foreign Keys. If I export code below I get an error however if I do not export with foreign keys I do not get an error could you have a look at the code for me.

SQL Code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`users` ;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`users` (
`uuserid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`ufname` VARCHAR(25) NULL ,
`ulname` VARCHAR(25) NULL ,
`uuname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
`upass` CHAR(64) NOT NULL ,
`uemail` VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL ,
`urole` INT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
PRIMARY KEY (`uuserid`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`photos` ;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`photos` (
`pphotoid` INT NOT NULL ,
`pname` VARCHAR(4) NULL ,
`plat` FLOAT(10,6) NULL ,
`plng` FLOAT(10,6) NULL ,
`pflag` DECIMAL(10,0) NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
`pext` VARCHAR(4) NULL ,
`plike` DECIMAL(10,0) NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
PRIMARY KEY (`pphotoid`) ,
CONSTRAINT `uuserid`
FOREIGN KEY ()
REFERENCES `mydb`.`users` ()
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') REFERENCES `mydb`.`users` () ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDAT' at line 21
```

My Database has many more tables but this code also breaks. I have tried to insert this using phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you need to specify the column name

```
FOREIGN KEY (present_table_column_name)
```

REFERENCES `mydb`.`users` (foriegn_key_column_name)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Not sure why this answer is marked down but I will pick as solved asap.

Comment: is there any problem with this

Answer (score 1):

Try running this script. I build this using your script and ran it in [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f05d7) so I know it works. In order to add a foreign key you have to have a field that will be appropriate. In this example I added a `uuserid` column in the `photos` table. This column has a foreign key constraint to the `uuserid` column in the `users` table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`users` ;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`users` (
`uuserid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`ufname` VARCHAR(25) NULL ,
`ulname` VARCHAR(25) NULL ,
`uuname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
`upass` CHAR(64) NOT NULL ,
`uemail` VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL ,
`urole` INT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`photos` ;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`photos` (
`pphotoid` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
`pname` VARCHAR(4) NULL ,
`plat` FLOAT(10,6) NULL ,
`plng` FLOAT(10,6) NULL ,
`pflag` DECIMAL(10,0) NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
`pext` VARCHAR(4) NULL ,
`plike` DECIMAL(10,0) NULL DEFAULT 0,
`uuserid`INT NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

Alter Table `photos` add constraint foreign key(`uuserid`) references `users`(`uuserid`);
```

In this example above, I moved the statement that sets the primary keys to the columns themselves rather than creating a statement at the end of the SQL.

I thought it would be a little clearer to show you how to add a foreign key constraint outside of the table creation so you can see what caused the syntax error. You had no column names in your foreign key references. Once added the above code will run perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error exactly where the error message tells you you have one.

The problem is you don't have you have any fields referenced in your constraint.  The form of the `CONSTRAINT` clause should be like this:

```
CONSTRAINT `fkuuserid`
FOREIGN KEY `fkuuserid` (some_field_in_this_table)
REFERENCES `mydb`.`users` (uuserid)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

I honestly don't even see where you have a logical foreign key on the photos table, as there is no uuserid field present in this table.